# bitwise operation, change bit from 0 to 1 then 1 to 0 without affect the other bit in same variabel 8 bit (uint8_t)

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a unsigned 8 bit variable SG1 which have value 0 or 1.
I want to put SG1's value at a new 8bit variabel (eg:coil) at 4th bit **without affect the other bit**.
can anyone help me ?

example :
uint8_t coil = 0b00010001;

SG1 = 0 or 1; //this value from the other function

expected result : (focus on 4th bit)
if SG1 == 1

coil change from the previous value (0b00010001) become 0b00011001;

then,

if SG1 == 0

coil change from the previous value (0b00011001) become 0b00010001;

below is the code that I build, it can work, but I want to change it without if else.

```
if(SG1 == 1){ //SG1 change from 0 to 1
    Coil |= (1 << 3);
}
else if(SG1 == 0){ //SG1 change from 1 to 0
    Coil &= ~(1 << 3);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a much simpler way. You could get rid of the branch by doing `Coil &= ~(1 << 3); Coil |= (SG1 << 3)`, but this is still repetitive.

Comment: What if the value is already the value you want?  (SG == 1 and the forth bit is 1 does it stay 1?  (same with SG == 0)